# PhpStorm with Ampps configuration

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm, ampps

If I have a subfolder in the directory"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\php.dev\myproject\index.php". I added the domain "php.dev" on Ampps, but whenever I run index.php a window pops up saying  404 error and another times I get:

> ERROR
>
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>   The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
>   http://php.dev/
>
> Access Denied.
>
> Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed
>   at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is
>   incorrect.

How can I add a domain to run the subfolder "myproject" inside "..www\php.dev\" folder? Is there a problem in PhpStorm or Ampps setting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved after removing and reinstalling Ampps.